# How to add support of "secure_link" to already installed OpenResty?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have an error in the logs of OpenResty:

```
unknown directive secure_link
```

I'm on Arch Linux and I installed OpenResty the standard way

```
yay -S openresty
```

How do I add support of **secure_link** to  it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. The only way to add new modules to nginx is to recompile it.

Here's a snippet from the [bash script](https://gist.github.com/DarkWiiPlayer/126c4247814b70434069d7cdf4b300ce) I use pretty much everywhere to install openresty:

```
latest='openresty-1.13.6.2'

apt-get -y install libpcre3-dev libssl-dev perl make build-essential curl libzip-dev

wget 'https://openresty.org/download/'$latest'.tar.gz'

tar -xzf $latest'.tar.gz'

cd $latest

./configure \
  --with-http_v2_module \
  --with-http_ssl_module \
&& make -j $(nproc) && make install || exit

cd ..
find -maxdepth 1 -name "$latest*" | xargs rm -rf
```

From there you should be able to copy and paste your way to a working openresty installation.

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux

Comment: @pivoche so what? Replace `apt-get` with whatever package manager you use, google the names of the packages if they are different and that's about it. `wget` works the same, `tar` works the same, pretty sure `cd` also works the same. I never claimed you could copy that snippet into your terminal as-is.

Comment: Once again: I installed OpenResty as `yay -S openresty`. Not manually. `yay` doesn't support all these `configure`, `make`

Comment: @pivoche Once again: YOU CAN'T. You *have* to recompile nginx. If you want to use a precompiled package, you'll just have to deal with it, unless there's a separate package with more features compiled in.